# Page keeps refreshing when updating html in javascript when I don't want it to

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to solve this problem, but the page keeps refreshing when it sets the innerhtml to something. I have worked on this for a while, but I can't figure it out. I have looked at other people's code, but haven't been able to figure it out myself.

Here is the code:

```js
function myFunction(){
var primes = [];

function isPrime(num) {
  for(var i = 2; i <= num/2; i++)
    if(num % i === 0 ) return false;
    primes.push(num);

}

function listOfPrimes(min, max) {
 for(var j = min; j < max; j++) 
  isPrime(j);
}

 


 
var minimum = document.getElementById('Minimum').value;
var maximum = document.getElementById('Maximum').value;

listOfPrimes(minimum,maximum);// DO NOT ENTER DECIMALS!!! minimum and maximum numbers that you want.
primes = primes.filter(function(x){ return x > 1});
primes = primes.toString();


document.getElementById("Your_Primes").innerHTML = primes;

}

var button = document.querySelector("button");
          button.addEventListener("click", function() {
                myFunction();
          });
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
 <title>Prime Lister</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>

Minimum Number:<br>
<input type="number" placeholder="MinimumWholeNumber" id="Minimum" multiple="1" required><br><br>
Maximum Number:<br>
<input type="number" placeholder="MaximumWholeNumber" id="Maximum" multiple="1" required><br><br>
<button>Enter</button>
</form>


<p>Your Primes: <p id="Your_Primes"></p></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Web_Prime_Lister.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are submitting `form` data. A `<form>` default action is to POST/GET so you need to prevent this from happening which can be done by using `.preventDefault();`

Comment: Try adding `event.preventDefault();` into your `click` event listener before calling `myFunction();`

Comment: @NewToJS Thanks! It Works! I will try to learn about things like this.

Comment: You can read more about `event.preventDefault()` at - [**MDN Web Docs - Event.preventDefault()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: This is a common mistake so this problem could be seen as a duplicate. I try to only submit solutions to questions I haven't seen before or that have a difference to others. I appreciate the offer though :)

Comment: @Spencer1O1, you have several mistakes in your code, including the one NewToJS speaks of. I've rearranged your code to a working version and explained what I did in my answer. Go ahead and run the code snippet to see it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some serious issues with your javascript. I rewrote your script and will append it to this answer with the correct javascript:

```js
var minimum;
var maximum;
var primes;

function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  minimum = document.getElementById('Minimum').value;
  maximum = document.getElementById('Maximum').value;
  primes = [];

  listOfPrimes(minimum, maximum); // DO NOT ENTER DECIMALS!!! minimum and maximum numbers that you want.  console.log(primes);
  primes = primes.filter(function(x) {
    return x > 1;
  });
  primes = primes.toString();
  document.getElementById("Your_Primes").innerHTML = primes;
}

function isPrime(num) {
  for (var i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++)
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  primes.push(num);
}

function listOfPrimes(min, max) {
  for (var j = min; j < max; j++) {
    isPrime(j);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  Minimum Number:<br>
  <input type="number" placeholder="MinimumWholeNumber" id="Minimum" multiple="1" required><br><br> Maximum Number:<br>
  <input type="number" placeholder="MaximumWholeNumber" id="Maximum" multiple="1" required><br><br>
  <button id="button" onclick="myFunction(event)">Enter</button>
</form>


<div>Your Primes:
  <p id="Your_Primes"></p>
</div>
```

I would tell you exactly what's wrong with your code but it's easier to tell you what I did. The basic logic you have in your functions is right but you just arranged it wrong. First, I instantiated the variables that you will use between your different functions to improve scope. Second, I set up your `myFunction` function that will be performed on click, inserting the functions that perform the logic and find the prime numbers, and preventing the event default that forces the page reload. Lastly I put your statements that you had outside of your on click function inside of it so it can update all the info every time the user changes the info and clicks the button. These statements include getting the min and max values, changing the array to a string, and setting the inner html. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I am just a beginner so this helps!

Comment: Glad I could help.. Happy Coding :)